# MySQL select that returns a dummy column?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way i can do a SELECT and tell it to return 3 columns and a dummy empty column ? I need 4 columns and the 3rd must be '' until the table is somewhere in the database. I am not allowed to add any columns to any tables.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Select column1, column2, 'waiting for table' as dummy_column, column4
from your_table
```

Comment: That column won't be empty will it?  Won't it be filled with "waiting for table'?

Comment: `Select column1, column2, NULL as dummy_column, column4
from your_table` will make the column NULL

Answer (score 20):

```
mysql> SELECT '' AS empty_col;
+-----------+
| empty_col |
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use for a column with empty string

```
Select column1, column2, '' as dummy_col, column 4 
  from your_table
```

or for a column with a Null value

```
Select column1, column2, Null as dummy_col, column 4 
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dummy column and keep the column rows empty you should use this instead:

```
Select column1, column2, '' as dummy_column, column4 
from your_table
```

This will add an empty column called dummy_column; whatever is populated in-between the quotation marks `''` is what what will appear as the dummy column's value.